# fatal: ambiguous argument 'branch' unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: linux, bash, git, github

I'm working on a script and inside that in one step I'm trying to get the latest commit hash of one of my git branches.

So my code looks like:

```
cd $sourceDirectory
COMMIT_HASH=$(git rev-parse $BRANCH_NAME)
echo "Commit hash is: $COMMIT_HASH"
```

But during execution of the script in my CI/CT pipeline, I'm getting the below error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '<branch-name>': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:

'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: It looks like `BRANCH_NAME` isn't set or contains garbage.

Comment: @vonbrand I did print the BRANCH_NAME variable prior to it and it has the right value